# Sitecore item API for shell site not returning the content

Tags: sitecore-api, links, item-web-api

When I click on the "**insert link**" of the general link field, then the complete tree is not opened (as shown in the screenshot below), due to which I am not able to select the item.

[image]

When I checked the console of the browser then I noticed that the following API is giving 200 status but not returning the item in **item[]** (see screenshot above)

```
https://<mydomain>/-/item/v1/sitecore/shell?sc_itemid={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}&scope=c&sc_database=master&language=en&fields=__Hidden
```

I am not sure what is the fault?

I have tried following:

1. Checked that item api is enabled
2. Logs have no clue regarding this issue
3. My project has no code where item api is extended.
4. All required templates and are present

Comment: Can you try rebuild the master index and see if the issue is fixed

Comment: I did that also, but not working

Comment: Can anybody tell me that which sitecore dll can I decompile and which class I can see to understand that how this API tries to load the tree?

Comment: did you check sitecore log files, any related errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for this has been found on the basis of the answer posted on my question asked in the Sitecore community.

For the general link field, the data source for the home node was passed below which all the pages are present. Now the tree is opening so that page can be selected now.

[image]